# How to use "map" data structure "in a query"

Tags: vespa

I want to include [map](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/search-definitions-reference.html#type:map) in a vespa *query* (not a document attribute) and lookup it in `expression`, but I have some questions.

1. Can I use `map` in a Vespa *query*?
2. If it's possible, how to lookup the elements in `expression`?
3. If it's impossible, can I use `mapped tensor` type instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass sparse values to a ranking expression accessing them individually (such as e.g an XGBoost or other GBTD model), pass them as individual query features: query(mykey) etc.

In a HTTP request:

```
ranking.features.query(mykey)=30.3
```

Or in Java code (in a Searcher):

```
query.getRanking().getFeatures().put("query(mykey", String.valueOf(30.3));
```

You may also want to assign a default value to each query feature used in your model. See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/ranking.html#using-query-variables

(You would use a mapped tensor query feature instead of many scalar query features instead if your model computed on the map as a whole, e.g by joining it with a document map.)

Comment: I see, understood. I heard that map in a query doesn't support elements lookup in a expression, but joining it with a document map enables that? (I don't want to prepare default values (=0) for each sparse dimension as you mentioned.)

Comment: Query features is itself a map of features already. A GBDT expression works on scalar features, not tensors, so you can 't use a tensor if you want the GBDT expression to work on individual values. With a GBDT you necessarily have a closed and fairly small set of features (aka possible entries in the map), so I don't see the problem with supplying default values for each query feature?

Answer (score 1):

There are examples on how to search map fields using sameElement query operator here https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/query-language-reference.html#sameelement but if I understand you correctly you want to pass a map as a query operator? If so the question if you want to use this for recall (which documents matches or purely as an input for ranking in a configured ranking expression? If the latter you can use tensors but tensors cannot be used for recall/search.

Comment: Is *recall* a placeholder in a expression fed as a query? If so, that's what I want to use.
I understood that:

- `map` is not usable for recall.
- `tensor` does not support elements lookup (index accessing).

Actually, what I realize is to pass sparse data to vespa at serving time, and use it for XGBoost's prediction. Is there any methods for that?